# Convert OrderBy Case statement in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to convert the following SQL from Oracle into a Linq to Entity query.

```
ORDER by
    case when(e.prev_co = 'ABC' and(nvl(co_seniority, '1-jan-2099') < to_date('10-apr-2001'))) 
            then '2001-04-01'
         else to_char(nvl(co_seniority, '1-jan-2099'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') end,
    nvl(co_seniority, '1-jan-2099'), 
    birth_dt
```

I was hoping I could use a function to pass in some parameters and have it return the correct date. I tried creating an new property called SortDate and then created a function on my page that would take in the parameters and return the correct date but that didn't work. I get and exception that says "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method GetSortDate".

```
Model
SortByDate = GetSortDate(e.PREV_CO, e.CO_SENIORITY),

Function

public static DateTime GetSortDate(string PreviousCo, DateTime? CoSeniorityDate)
{
    //set variable to default date
    DateTime sortDate = System.DateTime.Parse("2001-04-01");

    //set default date if NULL
    if (CoSeniorityDate == null)
    {
        CoSeniorityDate = System.DateTime.Parse("2099-01-01");
    }

    if (PreviousCo == "ABC" && (CoSeniorityDate < System.DateTime.Parse("2001-04-10")))
    {
        sortDate = System.DateTime.Parse("2001-04-01");
    }
    else
    {
        sortDate = System.DateTime.Parse(CoSeniorityDate.ToString());
    }

    return sortDate;
}
```

Here is my complete EF

```
using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
    db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;      //no changes needed so turn off for performance.

    var workStatus = new string[] { "1", "3" };
    var company = new string[] { "EX", "SM" };
    var eventReason = new string[] { "21", "22", "23" };

    data = (from e in db.EMPLOYEE
               where workStatus.Contains(e.WORKSTAT)
                   && company.Contains(e.CO.Substring(0, 2))
                   && ((e.EVENT_TYP != "35") || (e.EVENT_TYP == "35" && !eventReason.Contains(e.EVENT_RSN)))
            select new Employee
            {
                Co = e.CO,
                CityCode = e.CITY_CODE,
                EmployeeNumber = e.EMP,
                LastName = e.LAST_NAME,
                FirstName = e.FIRST_NAME,
                Position = e.ABV_POSITION_TITLE,
                EmploymentType = e.PART_TIME_IND == "X" ? "PT" : "FT",
                SeniorityDate = e.CO_SENIORITY == null ? DateTime.MaxValue : e.CO_SENIORITY,
                BirthDate = e.BIRTH_DT,
                SortByDate = GetSortDate(e.PREV_CO, e.CO_SENIORITY),
                PreviousCo = e.PREV_CO
            }).OrderBy(o => o.SortByDate).ThenBy(o => o.SeniorityDate).ThenBy(o => o.BirthDate).ToList();
}
```

Anyone have a suggestion on how I can convert this OrderBy?

---

**UPDATED QUESTION**

At the moment I have my query working correctly by using a secondary SELECT like @Markus showed. The first query just pulls the data and then all the formatting and calling of a method to get the correct SortByDate.

However, my manager would really prefer to do the sorting in the DB versus in memory. He let this one go because there are very few people calling this seniority list and only once a month.

For learning purposes I would like to see if I could get the DB to do all the sorting as @IvanStoev shows below. So, going back that route I’m not able to get the OrderBy to work exactly like it should.

If you look at the original SQL I’m trying to convert it first looks to see if the person had a previous company of “ABC” and if they do then look at the SeniorityDate (set a default date if that’s NULL) and compare it to an acquisition date. If that condition isn’t met then just use their SeniorityDate (set it’s default if NULL). Tricky….I know.

Using the suggested OrderBy in LinqPad and then looking at the returned SQL I can see that the first part of the OrderBy looks at the previous company and then the SeniorityDate and sets a value. Then it looks at the acquisition date. I need to somehow group some conditions to look at first which I don’t know it that’s possible.

```
SELECT t0.ABV_POSITION_TITLE, t0.BIRTH_DT, t0.CITY_CODE, t0.CO, t0.CO_SENIORITY, t0.EMP, t0.FIRST_NAME, t0.LAST_NAME, t0.PART_TIME_IND, t0.PREV_CO, t0.WORKSTAT
FROM SAP_EMPLOYEE t0
WHERE ((((t0.WORKSTAT IN (:p0, :p1) AND (t0.PERS_SUB_AREA = :p2)) AND SUBSTR(t0.CO, 0 + 1, 2) IN (:p3, :p4)) AND (t0.CO <> :p5)) AND ((t0.EVENT_TYP <> :p6) OR ((t0.EVENT_TYP = :p6) AND NOT t0.EVENT_RSN IN (:p7, :p8, :p9))))
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ((t0.PREV_CO = :p10) AND (t0.CO_SENIORITY IS NULL)) THEN :p11 WHEN (t0.CO_SENIORITY < :p12) THEN :p13 ELSE COALESCE(t0.CO_SENIORITY, :p11) END), COALESCE(t0.CO_SENIORITY, :p11), t0.BIRTH_DT
-- p0 = [1]
-- p1 = [3]
-- p2 = [200A]
-- p3 = [EX]
-- p4 = [SM]
-- p5 = [EXGS]
-- p6 = [35]
-- p7 = [21]
-- p8 = [22]
-- p9 = [23]
-- p10 = [ABC]
-- p11 = [1/1/2099 12:00:00 AM]
-- p12 = [4/10/2001 12:00:00 AM]
-- p13 = [4/1/2001 12:00:00 AM]
```

I need to come up with something like

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ((t0.PREV_CO = :p10) AND (COALESCE(t0.CO_SENIORITY, :p11) < :p12) THEN :p13 ELSE COALESCE(t0.CO_SENIORITY, :p11) END)
```

Here is the code I used in LinqPad.

```
void Main()
{
    var workStatus = new string[] { "1", "3" };
    var company = new string[] { "EX", "SM" };
    var eventReason = new string[] { "21", "22", "23" };

    var baseDate = new DateTime(2001, 4, 10);  // 10-apr-2001
    var minDate = new DateTime(2001, 4, 1);    // 1-apr-2001
    var abcDate = new DateTime(2001, 4, 10);   // 10-apr-2001
    var maxDate = new DateTime(2099, 1, 1);    // 1-jan-2099

    var data = (from e in SAP_EMPLOYEE
                where workStatus.Contains(e.WORKSTAT)
                        && e.PERS_SUB_AREA == "200A"
                        && company.Contains(e.CO.Substring(0, 2))
                        && e.CO != "EXGS"
                        && ((e.EVENT_TYP != "35") || (e.EVENT_TYP == "35" && !eventReason.Contains(e.EVENT_RSN)))
                orderby e.PREV_CO == "ABC" && e.CO_SENIORITY == null ? maxDate : e.CO_SENIORITY < abcDate ? minDate : e.CO_SENIORITY ?? maxDate,
                e.CO_SENIORITY ?? maxDate,
                e.BIRTH_DT
                    select new Employee
                    {
                        Co = e.CO,
                        CityCode = e.CITY_CODE,
                        EmployeeNumber = e.EMP,
                        LastName = e.LAST_NAME,
                        FirstName = e.FIRST_NAME,
                        Position = e.ABV_POSITION_TITLE,
                        EmploymentType = e.PART_TIME_IND == "X" ? "PT" : "FT",
                        SeniorityDate = e.CO_SENIORITY == null ? maxDate :
                            e.PREV_CO == "ABC" && e.CO_SENIORITY < twaDate ? maxDate : e.CO_SENIORITY,
                        LOA = e.WORKSTAT == "1" ? "LOA" : "",
                        ABC = e.PREV_CO == "ABC" ? "ABC" : "",
                        BirthDate = e.BIRTH_DT,
                        PreviousCo = e.PREV_CO
                    }).ToList();

    data.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Convert your query to List right after "where" and before "select". That will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the exception is that entity framework generates the SQL query when you execute it. In your case, this happens with the call to `ToList()` at the end. In order to generate the SQL query, entity framework analyzes the query and transforms it into SQL. As entity framework does not know your function, it cannot generate the SQL statements for it.

In order to solve this, you need to first execute the query and do the sort operation in memory on the results. In order to limit the amount of data that is transferred to the client, you should execute the query including the `where` clause and also tell EF which fields you are interested in to avoid a `SELECT * FROM ...` that includes all fields of the table.

You could change your query approximately as follows:

```
data = (from e in db.EMPLOYEE
           where workStatus.Contains(e.WORKSTAT)
               && company.Contains(e.CO.Substring(0, 2))
               && ((e.EVENT_TYP != "35") || (e.EVENT_TYP == "35" && !eventReason.Contains(e.EVENT_RSN)))
        select new ()
        {
            Co = e.CO,
            CityCode = e.CITY_CODE,
            EmployeeNumber = e.EMP,
            LastName = e.LAST_NAME,
            FirstName = e.FIRST_NAME,
            Position = e.ABV_POSITION_TITLE,
            EmploymentType = e.PART_TIME_IND == "X" ? "PT" : "FT",
            SeniorityDate = e.CO_SENIORITY,
            BirthDate = e.BIRTH_DT,
            PreviousCo = e.PREV_CO
        }).ToList().Select(x => new Employee() 
               {
                 Co = x.Co,
                 CityCode = x.CityCode,
                 EmployeeNumber = x.EmployeeNumber,
                 LastName = x.LastName,
                 FirstName = x.FirstName,
                 Position = x.Position,
                 EmploymentType = x.EmploymentType,
                 SeniorityDate = x.SeniorityDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue,
                 BirthDate = x.BirthDate,
                 SortByDate = GetSortDate(x.PreviousCo, x.SeniorityDate),
                 PreviousCo = x.PreviousCo
               }).OrderBy(o => o.SortByDate)
                   .ThenBy(o => o.SeniorityDate)
                   .ThenBy(o => o.BirthDate).ToList();
```

This query first filters the data as specified in the `where` clause and then uses an anonymous type to retrieve only the relevant fields - including the ones that are later used as an input to the `GetSortDate` method with its original values. After the first `ToList` the results are present in memory and you can first add a new select that creates the `Employee` objects including the sort date. These objects are then ordered by sort date and so on.

A small hint for the `GetSortDate` method: specifying DateTime constants as a string that is parsed is not a good idea as parsing is dependent on the culture of the thread (if no culture is specified).

```
// Culture dependent
sortDate = System.DateTime.Parse("2001-04-01");
// Better
sortDate = new DateTime(2001, 04, 01);
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize I could do two selects like that. I'm still learning EF/LINQ but the more I use it in the real world scenarios the more I'm learning. Looks like I have to tweak a little bit on the dates but this got me very close. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed (the hard way), in LINQ to Entities query you cannot use local methods like in LINQ to Objects. If you want the whole query to be executed in the database, you need to embed the logic inside the query using only the supported constructs.

With that being said, the equivalent of your SQL query should be something like this

```
var baseDate = new DateTime(2001, 4, 10); // 10-apr-2001
var minDate = new DateTime(2001, 4, 1);   // 1-apr-2001
var maxDate = new DateTime(2099, 1, 1);   // 1-jan-2099

data = (from e in db.EMPLOYEE
        where workStatus.Contains(e.WORKSTAT)
            && company.Contains(e.CO.Substring(0, 2))
            && ((e.EVENT_TYP != "35") || (e.EVENT_TYP == "35" && !eventReason.Contains(e.EVENT_RSN)))
        let seniorityDate = e.CO_SENIORITY ?? maxDate
        let sortDate = 
            e.CO_SENIORITY == null ? maxDate : 
            e.PREV_CO == "ABC" && e.CO_SENIORITY < baseDate ? minDate :
            e.CO_SENIORITY
        orderby sortDate, seniorityDate, e.BIRTH_DT
        select new Employee
        {
            Co = e.CO,
            CityCode = e.CITY_CODE,
            EmployeeNumber = e.EMP,
            LastName = e.LAST_NAME,
            FirstName = e.FIRST_NAME,
            Position = e.ABV_POSITION_TITLE,
            EmploymentType = e.PART_TIME_IND == "X" ? "PT" : "FT",
            SeniorityDate = e.CO_SENIORITY,
            BirthDate = e.BIRTH_DT,
            PreviousCo = e.PREV_CO
        }).ToList();
```

**Update:** For learning purposes I've updated the answer with using `let` clauses.

Now regarding the concrete ordering. I could have written the "SortDate" part exactly the way you did it, but I believe my way is a better equivalent. Why?

Here is my "SortDate" interpretation in pseudo code

```
if (CoSeniorityDate == null)
    SortDate = #2099-01-01#
else if (PreviousCo == "ABC" && CoSeniorityDate < #2001-04-10#)
    SortDate = #2001-04-01#
else
    SortDate = CoSeniorityDate
```

And here is your function

```
if (CoSeniorityDate == null) CoSeniorityDate = #2099-01-01#
if (PreviousCo == "ABC" && CoSeniorityDate < #2001-04-10#)
    SortDate = #2001-04-01#
else
    SortDate = CoSeniorityDate
```

Let `CoSeniorityDate == null`. Then, according to your logic, let substitute `CoSeniorityDate = #2099-01-01#`:

```
if (PreviousCo == "ABC" && #2099-01-01# < #2001-04-10#)
    SortDate = #2001-04-01#
else
    SortDate = #2099-01-01#
```

Since `#2099-01-01# < #2001-04-10#` is always **false**, it becomes simple

```
SortDate = #2099-01-01#
```

i.e. exactly like the first part of my criteria. In the else part we already know `CoSeniorityDate` is not **null** and can just check the other conditions.

Anyway, doing it your way would be like this

```
let sortDate = e.PREV_CO == "ABC" && seniorityDate < baseDate ? minDate : seniorityDate
```

Comment: Cool. Nice to see it done another way. It's more condensed this way. This also helps me tweak my dates some as well. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: @Caveman You welcome. Note that when possible, this is the preferable approach than  `ToList`/`AsEnumerable` at the middle and doing the rest in memory.

Comment: @Ivan...I've updated my question above. Do you have any suggestions on how I can tweak the OrderBy?

Comment: @Caverman Have you tried the way I wrote it? IMO it should produce the desired order.

Comment: Yes, I implemented what you sent and it came very, very close. As a matter fact it initially looked like all it missed was the second order by in the original OrderBy statement I posted. That why I started looking at what the SQL output was in LinqPad. BTW: I updated my update answer to include my LinqPad query.

Comment: @Ivan...thanks for all your help you're lending me. I'm trying to move my group from using in-line SQL to using LINQ and EF. They've been pretty good about trying to make the move but sometimes it gets hard with these complex queries because it takes me a while to convert them to LINQ all the while they are wanting me to just use the in-line SQL that was given because it works.